# Get the most recent location of many users

Tags: scala, scala-collections, list-manipulation

I believe there must be a better way to ask this question, but I couldn't think of it.

Consider this case class:

```
case class UserLocation(id: Int, dateTime: DateTime, lat: Double, lon: Double)
```

I have a `List[UserLocation]` with the history of all locations of all users, and I would like to filter this list to only have the most recent location from each of them.

Here is how I did it:

```
implicit def dateTimeOrdering: Ordering[DateTime] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_ isAfter _)

val locations: List[UserLocation] = bigListOfUserLocations()
val groupedById  = locations.groupBy(_.id)
val sortedByDate = groupedById.map(_._2.sortBy(_.dateTime))
val finalList    = sortedByDate.map(_.head)
```

This works, but what I would like to know is if there is a better way to do this, improving performance and/or readability

**IMPORTANT:** This is mostly an academic question, I would like to know the most performatic or most idiomatic way of achieving this on manipulating lists, so suggestions like *"try xyz on the database before you receive the list"* won't be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there, but you can reduce the last two operations to one with:

```
val finalList = groupedById.map(_._2.maxBy(_.dateTime))
```

This is more readable, and more performant, since you just find the biggest item in the group wihtout needing to put the rest in order.

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I wasn't aware of that `maxBy`method. Thank you

Comment: Be careful since `maxBy` is a partial function - `scala> List[(Int, Int)]().maxBy(_._1)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy`

Answer (score 0):

As has been already mentioned by [@Iadams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396556/6749977), there is no need to sort here. 
My solution doesn't improve readability, but improves performance a bit (although it's still `O(n)`) as it doesn't store all the locations for a user, but the most recent one, in one pass through the list:

```
locations
    .foldLeft(mutable.Map.empty[Int, UserLocation]) {
      case (acc, loc)
        if !acc.contains(loc.id) ||
          acc(loc.id).dateTime < loc.dateTime => acc.updated(loc.id, loc)
      case (acc, _) => acc
    }.map(_._2)
```